# Spring data neo4j DynamicProperties remove the prefix

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have an Entity like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private DynamicProperties properties = new DynamicPropertiesContainer();
}
```

All the properties I put in the dynamic properties will add a prefix `"properties-"`, can I configure something to remove this, say I put a key "name" and value "Neo" in this properties, and I can get a property "name" but not "properties-name"?

THX

Comment: this is just a workaround, you can run an update query on the graph where you first create all properties `name` with value of `properties-name` and then delete all properties of type `properties-name`. but i'm sure it can be handled just by some settings in spring :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I configure the spring settings to handle this? Can you give an example.